# Is it possible to bulk-edit a field across multiple entries at once?

Tags: entries, categories, editor

I would like to know if it's possible to select multiple entries and update a field for them all at once – for example, give all the selected entries the same category.

Comment: Are you asking if you can batch assign a custom field value to multiple entries at one time?

Comment: I'd like to be able to do this (a la Wordpress) [eg what Brad said above] — really handy for re-ccategorising entries.

Answer (score 3):

This plugin does it for Craft 3: https://github.com/kffein/craft-bulk-edit

Answer (score 2):

This has been requested in the Craft feedback forum (vote for it if you like, [here](https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/12473760-ability-to-batch-edit-field-values-on-multiple-ent) and [here](https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/13003440-ability-to-change-entry-values-from-the-cp-entries)). But as of Jan 2017, there is no functionality for this in a default Craft install.

The closest thing I've come across is the ***NP Edit Multiple Elements*** plugin which allows you to edit multiple entries *sequentially* meaning that when you hit save it automatically advances to the next entry – faster than the default, but not exactly a bulk edit tool.

See https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/np-edit-multiple-elements

I would love to see a bulk-edit plugin at some point, but someone will need to invest the time in building one.

Answer (score 1):

Via a plugin, yes.

Via the control panel interface, no.